# Copying "fancy" spaces with the mouse from Vim

Tags: vim, mouse, vimrc

I have the following setting in my .vimrc:

```
set listchars+=space:·
```

for formatting purposes (spaces vs tabs, extra spaces, etc) and thanks to  a proper color scheme, these dots do not disturb much. So far, so good. The problem is that when I select some text with the mouse to copy it and paste it with the mouse wheel, the spaces are copied as '·' and not as ' '. That does not happen inside Vim with regular copy operations or even if I copy the same text to the `*` register (when possible). That does not suffice though, because Vim does not support the clipboard feature in all the machines I access remotely and in those cases I still need the "bloody" mouse :)
Is there any way to avoid this apart from getting rid of my beloved setting in .vimrc? Highlighting the spaces or giving them a different color would be too annoying, by the way.

Example: original line on top and pasted one below. The grey dots are treated as spaces but the green ones are treated as proper dots.

[image]

Thanks a lot and best regards

Comment: I don't think you can solve this with vim: when you're copy/pasting with the mouse, you're just copying characters in your terminal window. The terminal doesn't know you're running `vim` or that the thing you are copying that is not a space should actually be a space.

Comment: You can define a command or macro prior to copying (yanking) and pasting _extrinsic_ of `vim`, to temporarily unset the setting(s) you have in place for visible whitespace, and reset it afterward.  `vim` has no way of knowing what you're going to do to its terminal, nor does your terminal emulator have any way to know whether a `·` is something you want it to parse as a space when copied thenceforth.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution I found: set list! to unset all my fancy characters, then copy, then set list! again :)